# Append geometry nodes object with linked objects in object info nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, append, asset-browser

I have a geometry nodes object that has several object info nodes. The objects in those nodes are all linked from another file.

When I append the geometry nodes object in a new file, all the objects from the object info nodes get appended as well. How can I make sure they are only linked?

The same problem occurs when I mark the geo nodes object as an asset and then add the asset to a scene.